# bibliography in scrbook

Tags: biblatex

I am using the WinEdt QuickGuide.tex as a template and tried to put in my bibliography with the following in my preamble:

```
\usepackage[refsection=chapter,defernumbers=true,sorting=none,sortcites=true,autopunct=true,babel=hyphen,hyperref=true,abbreviate=false,backref=true,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{C:/Superstar/Desktop/HomeWork/References/chap1.bib}
 \defbibheading{bibempty}{}
 \newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}
```

then in the document I used:

```
\chapter*{Bibliography}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\section*{Books}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Books}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=book,prefixnumbers={B}]
\section*{Articles}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Articles}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=article,prefixnumbers={A}]
\section*{Online}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Online}
\printbibliography[heading=bibempty,type=misc,prefixnumbers={O}]
```

but then I get the error `\protect...ing=bibempty,type=book,...`

Is it because I am using this command in the  `scrbook` class instead of the book class?  If so, how do I get around this issue in the `scrbook` class?

Here is a minimum example where the problem comes in:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn% syntax of expl3 on
%
\cs_new_eq:Nc \emph_old:n { emph~ } % Copying the old definition of `\emph`
\cs_new_eq:NN \emph_braces:n \textup % Braces should be typeset upright.
%
\cs_new:Npn \emph_new:n #1 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_emph_tl {#1}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {(}{\emph_braces:n{(}}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {)}{\emph_braces:n{)}}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {[}{\emph_braces:n{[}}
  \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {]}{\emph_braces:n{]}}
  \exp_args:NV \emph_old:n \l_emph_tl
}
%
% \emph umdefinieren, Sternvariante mit altem (=kursivem) Verhalten
\RenewDocumentCommand {\emph} {sm} {
  \IfBooleanTF {#1} {\emph_old:n {#2}} {\emph_new:n {#2}}
}
%
\ExplSyntaxOff% syntax of expl3 on


\begin{document}


\backmatter
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title=\bibname]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=book,prefixnumbers={B},title={Books}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,prefixnumbers={A},title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=online,prefixnumbers={O},title={Online}]

\end{document}
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Setting 'defernumbers=true' recommended.


Package biblatex Warning: Option 'prefixnumbers' requires global
(biblatex)                'defernumbers=true' on input line 33.

! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.33 ...type=book,prefixnumbers={B},title={Books}]
```

Comment: Don't use unnumbered sections, then  add manually a toc entry and then use an empty bib-heading. use `heading=subbibintoc` as option to `\printbibliography`.

Comment: Can you extend your question to a compilable example? If that is really a matter with `scrbook` i will drop i note to the maintainer.

Comment: @Johannes_B, I have included a min example of where the problem lies.

Comment: Please show the complete error message. btw, there won't be any bibliography because nothing is cited. If i add `\nocite{*}` i don't see any problem.

Comment: There is no indication, that this is related to `scrbook`. The first two are warning/recommendations, and in fact, option `defernumbers` is a very very good idea here. Is your version of `biblatex` up to date?

Comment: @Johannes_B my biblatex is updated

Comment: LaTeX stops compiling at the command: \printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=book,prefixnumbers={B},title={Books}]

Comment: You keep insisting that it doesn't work he? Good, i checked and it really doesn't. I want to apologize. The missing `\nocite` confused me, it is the L3 stuff that is making trouble. I'll take a look, but i have nearly no experience with L3.

Comment: Where does the redefiniton of `emph` come from?

Comment: See the update below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That bit of LaTeX3 code to set brackets and parenthesis upright inside emphasized parts *heavily* fights with the `titlecase` mechanism (maybe more) of `biblatex`.

One way to prevent this, is to locally switch back to the normal behaviour. That of course means, that parenthesis and brackets inside the bibliography or a cite will be italic. On the other hand, every command with an optional argument will *fail* within the new `emph`.

[image: joeNewEmph]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\ExplSyntaxOn% syntax of expl3 on

\cs_new_eq:Nc \emph_old:n { emph~ } % Copying the old definition of `\emph`
\cs_new_eq:NN \emph_braces:n \textup % Braces should be typeset upright.
\cs_new:Npn \emph_new:n #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_emph_tl {#1}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {(}{\emph_braces:n{(}}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {)}{\emph_braces:n{)}}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {[}{\emph_braces:n{[}}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {]}{\emph_braces:n{]}}
    \exp_args:NV \emph_old:n \l_emph_tl
}
\RenewDocumentCommand {\emph} {sm} {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1} {\emph_old:n {#2}}
    {\emph_new:n {#2}}
}
          %
\AtEveryCitekey{\RenewDocumentCommand{\emph}{m}{%
    \emph_old:n {#1}}
}
\AtBeginBibliography{\RenewDocumentCommand{\emph}{m}{%
    \emph_old:n {#1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff% syntax of expl3 on


\begin{document}
\nocite{averroes/hercz}

\emph{(Vater und Sohn)}\par
\emph*{(Vater und Sohn)}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: joeBiblatexL3Emph]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[defernumbers=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn% syntax of expl3 on

\cs_new_eq:Nc \emph_old:n { emph~ } % Copying the old definition of `\emph`
\cs_new_eq:NN \emph_braces:n \textup % Braces should be typeset upright.
\cs_new:Npn \emph_new:n #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_emph_tl {#1}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {(}{\emph_braces:n{(}}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {)}{\emph_braces:n{)}}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {[}{\emph_braces:n{[}}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_emph_tl {]}{\emph_braces:n{]}}
    \exp_args:NV \emph_old:n \l_emph_tl
}
\RenewDocumentCommand {\emph} {sm} {
    \IfBooleanTF {#1} {\emph_old:n {#2}}
    {\emph_new:n {#2}}
}
          %
\AtEveryCitekey{\RenewDocumentCommand{\emph}{m}{%
    \emph_old:n {#1}}
}
\AtBeginBibliography{\RenewDocumentCommand{\emph}{m}{%
    \emph_old:n {#1}}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff% syntax of expl3 on


\begin{document}
\fullcite{companion}

\emph{[test]}

\printbibliography

\nocite{*}

\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title=\bibname]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=book,prefixnumbers={B},title={Books}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,prefixnumbers={A},title={Articles}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=online,prefixnumbers={O},title={Online}]


\emph{[test)}\par
\emph*{[test)}

\end{document}
```

---

Package `biblatex` provides a bunch of macros to save you trouble. It takes care of setting the right title and puts it in the table of contents if you want it to be there.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\tableofcontents
\printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title=\bibname]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=book, title={books}]
\printbibliography[type=online, heading=subbibintoc, title={Online}]
\printbibliography[heading=subbibintoc,type=article,title={Articles}]
\end{document}
```